# Angular.js: How to http put a unique id and json data to REST API?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following template file:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <input type="text" ng-model="friend.name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="friend.gender">
    </li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

And I have the corresponding controller file:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'friends', '$http', function($scope, friends, $http) {
        $scope.title = "Home";
        $scope.friends = friends;
        $scope.save = function(){
            $http.put('http://localhost:8000/ip', friends)
            (JSON.stringify($scope.friends));
        };
    }]);
```

- My API takes PUT requests with the unique MongoDB _id to update single documents.
- Above template creates 2 input fields for each document in my collection (mongodb model).
- How can I alter my code to have a "Save"-Button next to each line and if clicked send a put request in the following format: `http://localhost:8000/ip/_id, jsondata`

Something like this: `<button ng-click="save(friend._id)" ng-model="friend._id" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>`

And in the controller something like this: `$http.put('http://westeros:9000/ip/:_id', friends)`

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <input type="text" ng-model="friend.name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="friend.gender">
        <button ng-click="save(friend)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'friends', '$http', function($scope, friends, $http) {
        $scope.title = "Home";
        $scope.friends = friends;
        $scope.save = function(friend){
            $http.put('http://localhost:8000/ip/'+ friend.id, friend )

        };
    }]);
```